# What is the normal usage brightness of the brightest Macbook currently available?

Tags: display

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro and [the tech specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=en_US) online says it's brightness is 500 nits, but it seems very dim in any sort of outside light is nearby.

[image]

When looking at Macbooks, the brightest I've seen listed is the [Macbook 14" and 16"](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-14-and-16/) and but the specifications are very confusing. They say they have one brightness setting for HDR that runs at 1000 nits and that can peak to 1600 nits (when?) and another brightness setting for SDR that is 500 nits. That's the same as I have right now.

What does that mean? What brightness level is it at for everyday use like surfing the web?

The Apple website shows this:

[image]

But it also says SDR is 500 nits:

[image]

When I was in the store there was no visible difference in brightness when compared side by side with other Macbooks.

Comment: According to https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/index-macbook-air.html, current MBP/MBA models still have 500 nits. But your question currently seems to ask several things at once (what does Apple offer, what will Apple offer, what does turbo/XDR mean, does it help me) which makes it difficult to get answers. Can you edit your question down to focus on one thing only?

Comment: Also, asking about what Apple will do in the future is off-topic in general.

Comment: @nohillside I've updated the question

Comment: SDR doesn't need 1600 nits because there's nothing in an SDR gamut that can stretch that far. I think you're confusing 'potential peak brightness' for specific image types, P3 etc, with 'how bright can my screen go if I'm in the sun trying to read the web'. If you're doing advanced colour repro work, first you get out of the sun ;) You have controlled lighting. For this in SDR, 120 nits is the standard, which makes most screens cranked up to the maximum far too bright to be actually useful..

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know that I need 1600 nits. But I would like more than 500. Supposedly I'm at 500 nits now with this macbook. What does SDR mean? There are times I will be in outdoor light so I do need increased brightness. The SDR part is confusing.

Comment: The DR part is Dynamic Range, S is Standard. X is eXtended. H is High. With an SDR image, if you lift the overall brightness, the blacks & dark greys get lighter too - this doesn't give better readability in bright light.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts SDR is standard dynamic range. It refers to the difference in brightness between the least and most bright parts of an image/color. HDR is high dynamic range and refers to content that has parts that are brighter than the brightest SDR colors.

Comment: So is normal use SDR, HDR or XDR? Is reading askdifferently SDR? Is using VSCode SDR?

Comment: Anything except high-budget Hollywood is SDR, basically, & only a very few places you can see HDR in all its glory. A few TV shows are broadcast [actually streamed, they can't properly broadcast it] in HDR, if you have the right subscription & a capable TV. David Attenborough's Planet Earth II for instance was streamed in 4k HDR. [Much HDR content posted on YouTube, for instance, is clueless amateurs pushing bad content with an HDR sticker on it to draw the unwary.

Comment: I can't imagine any circumstances in which the new Macs aren't bright enough for any usage.

Comment: @benwiggy do you live in the north pole? if not take one outside during the day and tell me how it goes :)

Comment: @Tetsujin then you understand what my question is about. If normal PC use is SDR than that means I only get 500 nits brightness with this computer unless I'm watching at movie on my computer that's in HDR and then it's 1000 or 1600. Is the answer then that this only runs at 500 nits for normal pc use?

Comment: Why doesn't the operating system tell you the brightness it's displayed at? Why is this so difficult? Can someone reopen the question?

Comment: I've updated the question and the question body

Comment: The question is closed - but here is my answer: Remember when comparing the specs of old Macs with new Macs that brightness can actually deteriorate. Your old MacBook Pro has an LED-backlit display that won't dim over time as quickly as older display technologies, but it does actually still degrade. How much depends on how many hours the display has been on. As I read your question, you basically want to increase general brightness - you're not concerned with peak brightness in achieving optimal contrasts when viewing movies or similar. For your case, you can use the app "Vivid" [...]

Comment: [...] and other similar apps to increase the general brightness of your system on new Macs with XDR displays. If you're often found using your MBP outside with lots of sun light, this can make a huge difference. Essentially you're going to experience something that comes close to a doubling of brightness. So in this comparison a new 14" MacBook Pro can have much higher brightness than your older 2017 MacBook Pro.

Comment: @jksoegaard thank you. yes, the display has been on for long durations and if not for work it's on as a screensaver. can i use "vivid" with my current macbook or do i need one with the xdr display? btw I completely rewrote the question and you're comment shows that you understood it. maybe it can be reopened so you can post your comments as an answer

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Unfortunately, Vivid requires the XDR display to function. The older displays can only deliver 500 nits - they do not have that "extra gear" that an XDR display has. With a new MacBook Pro you can unlock that 1000 nits with Vivid. Note that there's also disadvantages to using Vivid, so I would only use it when required. The biggest disadvantage is that it drains your battery faster, but I guess it is obvious that doubling the amount of light requires more power. I still find it very practical and useful when doing work outside in the sun. Battery life is superb anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac with the brightest, built-in display is currently the 14" and 16" MacBook Pro. They have a display capable of 500 nits in SDR mode and 1000 nits sustained in XDR mode - with peaks of up to 1600 nits.

What you will experience in "normal usage" depends on what is normal usage for you. You indicate that this is browsing the web. That would usually be SDR content, meaning that if you set the display to full brightness, it would be 500 nits.

When you compare that spec to your old Mac - remember that the backlighting (and thus brightness) can actually deteriorate over time.

Your old MacBook Pro has an LED-backlit display that won't dim as quickly over time as older display technologies, but it does actually still degrade. How much depends on how many hours the display has been on.

As I read your question, you basically want to increase general brightness - you're not concerned with peak brightness in achieving optimal contrasts when viewing movies or similar.

For your case, you can use the app "[Vivid](https://www.getvivid.app)" and other similar apps to increase the general brightness of your system on new Macs with XDR displays. Note that this requires a recent MacBook Pro with an XDR display - the app cannot increase general perceived brightness on your older 2017 MacBook Pro.

If you're often found using your MBP outside with lots of sun light, this can make a huge difference. Essentially you're going to experience something that comes close to a doubling of brightness. So in this comparison a new 14" MacBook Pro can have much higher brightness than your older 2017 MacBook Pro.